# Disable "sleep" shortcut on backspace key on Thinkpad P73

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P73 running Windows 10. The <kbd>backspace</kbd> key above the number pad doubles, for some reason, as a *sleep* shortcut key:

[image]

I use the number pad a lot and regularly hit this key by accident, and it's extremely irritating (like, HR-complains-about-my-language-at-work level irritating).

Is there a way to disable the *sleep* shortcut on this key? I didn't find any settings in Lenovo Vantage or in the keyboard control panel, and I'm having trouble doing an internet search because of how generic the words are.

One of the strange things about this key is its functionality is reversed compared to the <kbd>F?</kbd> keys and their shortcuts. By default, with <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> off, the <kbd>F?</kbd> keys do shortcuts (*volume* and such) but the <kbd>backspace</kbd> functions as *backspace*, while with <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on, the <kbd>F?</kbd> keys are the F keys but the <kbd>backspace</kbd> is *sleep*.

Since I use the <kbd>F?</kbd> keys regularly I keep <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on, so while I know turning <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> off at least requires me to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> with <kbd>backspace</kbd> to *sleep*, I keep <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on almost all the time, so that's not a solution. However, I would accept a solution that just swaps the functionality (<kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> on requires <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to sleep) as an alternative to disabling it.

If I can't find a software configuration solution, the fallback plan is to just physically remove the key, since I don't really need it. But I'd rather not do that, for various reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution would be to. . .

1. Go in "**Power & Sleep**" settings
2. Then "**Additional power settings**"
3. Select "**Choose what the power buttons do**"
4. Select "**When I press the sleep button: `Do nothing`**"

[image]

Comment: OH MY GOD. IT WORKED. Fantastic. Thank you *so much*; I've been hunting for this *everywhere*.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Nice image; it's the wrong setting though lol. It's "when I press the *sleep* button". I'm going to edit the image out for now, sorry.

Comment: @JasonC .... All good man, just trying to keep the content as helpful as possible to everyone now and moving forward. Might as well make it be as accurate as what helped you!!

Comment: There ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​we go.​​ ​​ ​​

Comment: @JasonC --> That worked! And what a terrible place for a sleep button. A dedicated backspace button that worked while in Fn Lock would be a trillion times more useful.

Comment: Two backspace keys on the same keyboard is also strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution by Ben, there is another location that you might want to check if something doesn't work as expected. The setting above is for all power plans, but apparently the plan itself can still override.

In the Power Options overview click on "Change Plan Settings" and then "Change advanced power settings". Scroll down to "Power buttons and lid" and set the Sleep button action to "Do Nothing". Note that this does not affect the general setting except if the plan you're editing is the "recommended" plan.

[image: configuration of power plan]

In my case the general setting was set for the PC to go to sleep when pressing the sleep button, but in the details of the currently used power plan it was set to "do nothing", so for this power plan, nothing happened when pressing the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the FnLock key so if it's on, you have the special functions and if off you use the Fn-keys. But the keys above the number pad aren't reversed! So if the FnLock is off, you have the Fn-keys and the '=' and Backspace.

The option is in Lenovo Vantage settings at Devices > Input ...
[image: Lenovo Vantage settings (in Dutch)]

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo support has an [article](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103044/?clickid=S-F0sXwjixyOUDMwUx0Mo3cjUknX3U3%3APzkyVU0&irgwc=1&PID=269814&acid=ww%3Aaffiliate%3Abv0as6) about this. Basically you have your hotkeys set in a specific mode that is causing them to act in the way that you describe. Try their <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> suggestion to modify this on your Thinkpad.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer, but I just read that article and unfortunately it just describes how to enable (or disable) Fn lock, which I already have enabled. The "Fn lock" key I mention in my question is, in fact, "Fn + Esc"; and I've already hunted through Vantage and BIOS settings to no avail. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a machine on which to test this program, but [Simple Disable Key](https://www.techworld.com/download/system-desktop-tools/simple-disable-key-30-3331033/) may be of some assistance in your objective. The configuration is to start the program, select the combination to be disabled by pressing the key.

Another option would be a similar program [Disable Key](https://disable-key.en.uptodown.com/windows) which functions in the same manner.

The former program does not have a tick box for FN while the latter one does not require such a preliminary and merely requires the key press to register the feature to the key.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both applications. Strangely, neither recognize any keypresses when the sleep shortcut key is pressed. Oddly, they don't recognize this keyboard's calculator shortcut key above the number pad either. They recognize all the rest of the shortcut keys, though.  :(

Comment: That figures. I suspect the key you want to disable is within the BIOS/UEFI and proprietary.

Comment: Yeah; there's no useful BIOS settings, the only related setting there is the default power-on `Fn Lock` state. I *did* find a Lenovo forum post about somebody's number pad shortcut keys not working, and the solution was to reinstall the hotkey drivers, which isn't directly relevant but *does* imply that it is at least handled by software drivers somewhere, which gives me a little bit of hope, I guess. I'll play around with services and drivers later to see if I can at least narrow it down. The device manager doesn't show any special keyboard drivers though, just a generic PS/2 driver.